# Angularjs watch input binding change for Array when using ControllerAs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controlleras, angularjs-components

I have an AngularJs component having bindings to heroes, which is an array. How to watch this input for array changes? I tried `$scope.watch("heroes", ...)` and `$onChanges`, but didn't work so far.

```
bindings: {
    heroes: '<',
}
```

Here is my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/J8xeqEQftGq3ULazk8mS?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ControllerAs structure needs a special watch expression, since the attributes are not on the $scope.

```
//This one works and is the best one (> AngularJs 1.5)
$scope.$watch("$ctrl.heroes.length", function () {
  console.log("ControllerAs syntax"); // Triggers once on init
});

//This one works as well
var ctrl = this;
$scope.$watch(() => {
  return ctrl.heroes.length;
}, (value) => {
  console.log("complex watch"); // Triggers once on init
});
```

See example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/J8xeqEQftGq3ULazk8mS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because $scope.$watch by default doesn't deeply watch objects. Which means since you never destroy/recreate your array, the reference doesnt really change therefore `$scope.$watch` doesnt see any change. If you watched `heroes.length`, that primitive would change and your `$scope.$watch` would fire the corresponding listening function. By using `$scope.$watch` with the `true` option you are telling the angular engine to deeply watch all properties.
This is pretty intensive to do for large objects because `$scope.$watch` using `angular.copy` to track changes

If you were to use `$scope.$watchCollection` angular would create a shallow copy and would be less memory intensive. So I feel your 3 main options are

Watch `heroes.length` , add `true` or use `$watchCollection`

I feel that using `heroes.length` would be your best bet, so the code would look like

`$scope.$watch('heroes.length',function(){});`

The other two options are described below

`$scope.$watch('heroes',function(){
    //do somthing
    },true)`

or

```
$scope.$watchCollection
```

The benefit of using watchCollection is, that it requires less memory to deeply watch an object.

> Shallow watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of
>   the properties change (for arrays, this implies watching the array
>   items; for object maps, this implies watching the properties). If a
>   change is detected, the listener callback is fired.
>
> The obj collection is observed via standard $watch operation and is
>   examined on every call to $digest() to see if any items have been
>   added, removed, or moved. The listener is called whenever anything
>   within the obj has changed. Examples include adding, removing, and
>   moving items belonging to an object or array.

Comment: I tried all of your suggestions, but none worked for me. I added a plunker to my question.

Comment: It was due to my ControllerAs structure. I added that part at the bottom of your answer. Maybe AngularJs will provide some easier way in the future.